# In a while loop select only rows with different values of a column

Tags: sql

I've got the following table:

```
ID   User   Data
1    isma   A
123  john   B
456  lucy   A
789  isma   A
111  luke   A
```

And I want to select all those users whose values are only `A` but I don't want `isma` to appear twice, I mean select only unique users and please don't advise me to set a UNIQUE index on users because I can't. I'd be very grateful with any answer :)

This is my SQL: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE data = 'A'` but of course it outputs the user `isma` twice.

Comment: Use `DISTINCT` in your `SELECT` like so: `SELECT distinct user,data FROM t WHERE data = 'A'`

Comment: Out of two `isma` (i.e. Id = 1 and Id = 789) which one you want to see in result

Comment: What rdms do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT DISTINCT User FROM table WHERE data = 'A';
```

**Output**

```
| User |
|------|
| isma |
| lucy |
| luke |
```

If you also want the count of users with same name and with `Data = 'A'` you can use `Group By`

```
SELECT User,
       COUNT(*) AS 'User Count'
FROM table 
WHERE Data = 'A'
GROUP BY User;
```

**Output**

```
| User | User Count |
|------|------------|
| isma |          2 |
| lucy |          1 |
| luke |          1 |
```

Comment: `DISTINCT` is an awful key word ;)  It screws you over when you want to do *anything* else.  Best bet is usually a `GROUP BY`...

Comment: @MatBailie i agree but since OP only wanted unique Users, i answered with the simplest query. Anyways included the `Group By` version of query with the count of users with same name and with `Data = 'A'`